# The total amount and quantity of goods in the order Opencart 2.3

Tags: php, opencart

How do I get the total amount and quantity of goods in the order? I want to display it on the page account.php in Opencart 2.3. There is such an entry in the order.php controller.

```
// Totals
$data['totals'] = array();
$totals = $this->model_account_order
    ->getOrderTotals($this->request->get['order_id']);

foreach ($totals as $total) {
    $data['totals'][] = array(
        'title' => $total['title'],
        'text' => $this->currency->format($total['value'],
            $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some sort of counter in the "foreach" loop that's running.

The counter will be incremented for every time the loop runs, or so to say for every item in the cart.

Then the Counted value becomes your total no of products.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).